# Cant get nav bar to hide content when I scroll up

Tags: html, css, image

I am building a landing page and am wondering why I cant get my navbar to work properly. I formatted it right, but one issue I am running into is when I scroll down the text goes through the nav bar/header when it should be going behind it or not visible when you scroll down. Anybody know a way that I can fix this issue? Here's the code that I have:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vanderlay Industries</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header">
    <img id="header-img" src=http://nextarts.info/wp-content/uploads/art-vandelay-06-quotplaying-with-powerquot-art-vandelay.jpg alt="Vanderlay President">
    <div>
      <h1>Vandelay Industries, Inc.</h1>
      <p id="subtitle">Importer/Exporter of Fine Latex Goods</p>
    </div>

    <div>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#demonstration">Demonstration</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="features">
    <h2 class="title">Features</h2>

    <div id="fine">
      <h3 class="title">Fine</h3>
      <img id="fine-image" src="https://f4.bcbits.com/img/0007459691_10.jpg" alt="Fancy Fine Lettering">

      <p class="description">What we sell is always of the finest quality. Founded on February 12, 1992; no higher standard of fine has been met. Whether it be the local fire department or public water supply, we've set the bar for the finest. With Vandelay, you'll always be
        enjoying the finer things</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Latex">
      <h3 class="title">Latex</h3>
      <div>
      <img id="latex-image" src="http://mjtrends.b-cdn.net/images/product/963/pearlsheen-metallic-blue-latex-sheeting_370x280.jpg" alt="Latex Image">
      </div>
      <p class= "description">Our latex is so strong you couldn't even fabricate it. Or make a ficticious firm about it. That's how authentic our latex is. Try it today.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Goods">
      <h3 class="title">Goods</h3>
      <img id="goods-image" src="http://wefirstbranding.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/virtual-goods1.jpg" alt="Pile of Goods">
      <p>If you got the goods, you got the goods. And we got em. Lots of em. Whether it be potato chips or diapers, the goods at our firm are plentiful.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="demonstration">
    <h2>Latex Demonstration</h2>
    <iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p8qnYz5jHag"></iframe>
    <p>Take the pleasure of viewing a sublime presentation of latex</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pricing">
    <div class="productLabel">
      <h4>Latex 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$1,000</h3>
      Our base model. Very popular option.
    </div>
    <div class="productLabel">
      <h4>Latex 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$5,000</h3>
      A more luxury material from the far land of Bosco.
    </div>
    <div class="productLabel">
      <h4>Latex 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$10,000</h3>
      The finest we offer, genetically superior good through marine biology.
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <p>For more information, please enter your email below. We will be happy to send you a free latex demonstration!</p>
    <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
      <label for=email>Enter your email address:</label>
      <input id="email" type=email name="email" required>

      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </section>
  <footer>
    &copy; Vandelay Industries Inc.
  </footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 128, 90%);

  color: #f7ed36;
}

#nav-bar {
  color: #f7ed36;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul {
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #f7ed36;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: 25px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 128, 90%);

}
#subtitle {
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 17px;
  left: 5px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

#header-img {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.description {
  align: baseline;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: ;
}

#features{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;

}

#fine-image {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 10px;

}
#latex-image {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;

  margin: 10px;

}
#goods-image {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 10px;

}
```

Any thoughts you have is appreciated. I'm sure its pretty common thing to fix since a lot of pages online have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 128, 90%);
  z-index: 2
}
```

Looks like header would be a sticky header.
If you need header layer to be in front of the page, must use z-index to order the layer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a Try!

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 128, 90%);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999
}
```

All in that [Z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)